# (swift/xcode) Error message: 'Setting this node as parent would create a loop'

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

What does this error message mean? I can't find anything at all on Google about it. And any ways to fix it would be nice. For reference this is the full error message:

`2017-05-15 10:09:10.942 Tetris[2258:77198] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Setting this node as parent would create a loop: <SKNode> name:'(null)' position:{6, -6} scale:{1.00, 1.00} accumulatedFrame:{{12, -412}, {200, 400}}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa4dd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cacb21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fab72b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   SpriteKit                           0x000000010cfe3134 -[SKNode(setParent) setParent:] + 87
    4   SpriteKit                           0x000000010cfdc376 -[SKNode insertChild:atIndex:] + 230
    5   SpriteKit                           0x000000010cfdc26f -[SKNode addChild:] + 68
    6   Tetris                              0x000000010c4bafe0 _TFC6Tetris9GameScenecfT4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 1376
    7   Tetris                              0x000000010c4bb080 _TFC6Tetris9GameSceneCfT4sizeVSC6CGSize_S0_ + 64
    8   Tetris                              0x000000010c4c23f2 _TFC6Tetris18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 274
    9   Tetris                              0x000000010c4c3222 _TToFC6Tetris18GameViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010d368a3d -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1258
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010d368e70 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010d2324b5 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010d232c06 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010d246519 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010d1bef8d -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c50ed -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c226d -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116a4b6cb __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116a4b544 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000116a4b8cd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9f2761 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9d798c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9d6e76 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9d6884 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c0aea -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010d1c6c68 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  Tetris                              0x000000010c4c858f main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001109fd68d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably what is happening is that you're trying to create a paradoxical node hierarchy.

As you probably know, nodes can have parents and children.  You need to ensure that, as you set the relationships of these nodes, that you're not creating a "loop" where a child ends up being an ancestor of its parent.

For example, if you have a node "A", and you create a new node "B" and add it as the child, you cannot then turn around and add "A" as a child of "B" because this will create a loop.

Similarly, you cannot have "A" with a child of "B" and then make "C" a child of "B" and then have "A" be a child of "C".  And so on.  Basically, you cannot have a situation where a node will show up as both an ancestor and a descendant.

This is important because the hierarchy needs to be well-defined.  You need to be able to, say, traverse through the ancestors of a node to find the "root" node, or to figure out its position in the reference frame of a node higher up.  If you create a loop of ancestry, these sorts of recursive searches up the ancestry of your nodes will create infinite loops, so it is important to avoid them.  SpriteKit does you a solid and checks when you make relationships to ensure that you're not doing that.  Hence, the error.

Comment: I realised what I did - that I had two nodes similarly named, and by using the wrong one had set A as a child of B and B as a child of A, rather than B as a child of C (which was similarly named to A).

Comment: Ah, yes, that would explain it.  One good habit that helps avoid that is to ensure all nodes are uniquely named.